# Pub install stalls on "running pub install" dialog

Tags: dart, dart-pub, dart-editor

I'm running pub install so I can use the intl package (I need to use the DateFormat class) that's part of the dart sdk.  I've installed other packages into my project such as the XML parser and presentation (similar to impress js). I had no trouble running pub install in the past when I installed the packages that are currently included in my project, but today it just sits in the "running pub install" dialog. I took the intl package declaration out of the yaml file and attempted to update, but it would still hang. I don't get an error message or any indication that the request to install the package is actually being processed.

So, I'm asking whether or not there is a known issue with the pub install feature? What can I do in the meantime?

Here's my yaml code:

```
name:  test_client
description:  A sample application

dependencies:
xml:
 git: https://github.com/prujohn/dart-xml.git
presentation:
 git: https://github.com/CatalystItLabs/presentation.dart
intl:
 sdk: intl
```

Please note that the xml and presentation packages are installed. I reached out to the dartlang community via twitter, but I haven't yet received a response.

Comment: It's much better to ask questions here than on Twitter.

Comment: Your yaml formatting is probably causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using git read-only version

```
dependencies:
xml:
 git: git://github.com/prujohn/dart-xml.git
```

i try https before doesn't work but this work

Comment: Thx but I'm trying to install the intl package.

Comment: Sorry...I misunderstood your answer.  Looks like what you were suggesting is the solution to my problem.  TY!

Answer (score 1):

I've filed a bug http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=6843 about analogous problem.
Feel free to star it to stay tuned for news about possible fixes.

Comment: Ok thank you.  I read your bug post and the responses.  It looks like the problem is with generating the lock file...